# iOS objectAtIndex beyond bounds

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, tableview, reloaddata

I have a table that is populated by an array of objects and whenever I call my refresh method that re-populates the array and reloads the table, when I try to read my array in cellForRowAtIndexPath I get a beyond bounds error. I have NSLogged my array to make sure it is populated correctly, and it is. It always is trying to read an index 1 larger than the array is actually. I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"IndexPath = %d", indexPath.row);

// Returns the cell for the given indexPath
static NSString *cellidentifier1 = @"cell1";
static NSString *cellidentifier2 = @"cell2";

self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dark-background.jpg"]];
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dark-background.jpg"]];

// Invisible Cell
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {

    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier2];

    if (cell2 == nil) {

        cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier2];
    }

    [cell2.contentView setAlpha:0];
    [cell2 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [cell2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    return cell2;
}

// Standard Cell                    
FCTableViewCell *cell = (FCTableViewCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier1];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[FCTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier1];
}

FCCall *currentCall = [[dataController calls] objectAtIndex:((indexPath.row - 1 ) / 2)];

cell.callLabel.text = currentCall.call;
cell.locationLabel.text = currentCall.location;
cell.wcccaNumberLabel.text = currentCall.wcccaNumber;
cell.callNumberLabel.text = currentCall.callnumber;

// Remove leading white space from units string
NSString *units = [currentCall.units stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

cell.unitsLabel.text = units;
cell.stationLabel.text = currentCall.station;

if ([currentCall.county isEqualToString:@"W"]) {

    cell.countyImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"];
}
else {
    cell.countyImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];
}

if ([currentCall.callType isEqualToString:@"F"]) {

    cell.callTypeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];
}
else {
    cell.callTypeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"];
}

[cell.unitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(unitButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.unitButton.tag = ((indexPath.section & 0xFFFF) << 16) |
(indexPath.row & 0xFFFF);

[cell.directionsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(directionsButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.directionsButton.tag = ((indexPath.section & 0xFFFF) << 16) |
(indexPath.row & 0xFFFF);

return cell;
}
```

numberOfRowsInSection:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Returns the number of rows per section        
    return [dataController calls].count * 2;
}
```

refresh method:

```
[dataController refreshData:self success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURL *url, NSArray *calls) {

        [self setWork:calls];
        NSLog(@"Array = %@", work);

        // Reset the pull controller and reload the table
        [pull finishedLoading];
        [tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURL *url, NSError *error) {

        // Reset pull indicator
        [pull finishedLoading];

        // Reload table
        [tableView reloadData];
    }];
```

refresh method:

```
- (void)refreshData:(id)object success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSURL *url, NSArray *calls))success failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSURL *url, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSLog(@"Refresh Started");

    // Start the network activity indicator
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    // Check to make sure we can even make an HTTP request
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wccca.com/PITS"]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"Reachable");

        // Get the URL we are going to use to parse with
        [FCDataController parserURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wccca.com/PITS"] completion:^(NSURL *url) {

            NSURLRequest *parserRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:parserRequest success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {

                // Initialize our calls array that will control our calls
                calls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                // Set the delegate for the XMLParser and start the parse operation
                XMLParser.delegate = self;
                BOOL successful = [XMLParser parse];

                // Determine if the parse operation was a success or not
                if (!successful) {

                    // Return the failure block because the parser failed
                    failure(request, url, [FCErrors parserError]);

                    // Stop the network activity indicator
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                }
                else {

                    // Return the success block
                    success(request, url, calls);

                    // Stop the network activity indicator
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                }

                NSLog(@"Refresh Finished");

            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {

                NSLog(@"AFXMLOperation Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

                // Remove all data from our previous calls aray
                [self setCalls:nil];

                failure(parserRequest, url, [FCErrors badURLError]);

                // Stop the network activity indicator
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

                NSLog(@"Refresh Finished");
            }];
            [operation start];
        }];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Unreachable. AFHTTPRequestOperation Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

        // Remove all data from our previous calls aray
        [self setCalls:nil];

        failure(request, nil, [FCErrors networkError]);

        // Stop the network activity indicator
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

        NSLog(@"Refresh Finished");
    }];
    [requestOperation start];
}
```

Comment: Make sure this line is correct: `FCCall *currentCall = [work objectAtIndex:((indexPath.row - 1 ) / 2)];` It's the only one I see using an array.

Comment: What's in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` method?

Comment: return work.count * 2;

Comment: The reason I have all the arithmetic is because I have an invisible cell in between each visible cell. row 0: invisible row 1: visible etc.

Comment: @darkfoxmrd I have updated it.

Comment: What's an invisible row?

Comment: I meant to say, invisible cell. Every even cell is invisible as laid out in cellForRowAtIndexPath and every odd cell is visible, to give a spaced look in the cells.

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would cause that error. Have you put in an exception breakpoint to see what line causes the error? Have you logged indexPath.row to confirm that a number 1 greater than 2 times your count is being passed in?

Comment: I have put in a exception breakpoint and it still breaks at the same line.

Comment: Its weird, I NSLogged indexPath.row, and whenever I call my refresh method, which re-populates the array and reloads the data, it logs a row way higher than in the array.

Comment: And thing is, the error is ONLY thrown when my array goes from a higher number to a low number. If you were to refresh the array going from lower and adding more to the array, and then reload the Table, the error does not occur.

Comment: It sounds like your error has something to do with the refreshData:success:failure: method (or in setWork?). You should post the code for that.

Comment: I have NSLogged my array as you can see above and it returns 2 objects with a count of 2, yet during cellForRowAtIndexPath it NSLogs indexPath.row 6/7. Ill post it the refreshData method.

Comment: I FINALLY figured it out. Simply by switch [pull finishedLoading] and [self.reload tableview] around. I should of had the table reload the table BEFORE the pull to refresh view finished loading because calling [pull finishLoading] restores the view and scrolls the table up at the same time, cause index 6 and 7 to be re-drawn, when the table HADNT been reloaded with the new array data, if that makes sense.

Comment: @JonErickson You should make your final comment an answer and accept it to mark this question as answered.